# How can I edit custom vm option outside of PhpStorm?

Tags: linux, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I added one line text on custom vm options and after that I can't open PhpStorm.
Here is my error text:

> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing

Where is custom vm options file location on Linux ? On Windows I found it at user folder.

Comment: Check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985 -- it should give you the answer. But in general -- Linux should be similar to Windows in this regard (the overall idea for where to find such files). It's Mac that is a bit different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i found file location
/home/username/.PhpStorm2019.3/config/phpstorm64.vmoptions
just type ls -a in  terminal and you can see phpstorm config folder in roor directory

Answer (score 3):

For Linux，

```sh
sudo su
find / -name *.vmoptions
```

Then you will find it！

Comment: It is a good advice to search automatically for the file, however, there are two small errors in the command: 
1. remove the su or make two commands out of it 
2. put the name (in this case *.vmoptions) into quotation marks. Otherwise your shell might replace it with the file ending with `.vmoptions` in your current directory and you won't find everything. So the correct command would be `sudo find / -name "*.vmoptions"`. Also it very probable that the file is inside $HOME, so `find ~ -name ".vmoptions"` might be better

Comment: Take a look to the .config/JetBrains/PhpStormVERSION inside your home directory (where version is your PhpStorm Version)